# .Net Micro Framework, Digi Connect ME on version 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

Has anyone devised a way to run versions of .Net Micro Framework on the Digi Connect ME? Digi stopped working with .Net MF at version 2.5. Thanks.

Comment: have you contacted the vendor on their plans?

Comment: Digi Connect ME Digi JumpStart Kit for .NET Micro Framework 2.5, including Visual Studio 2005 (90-day trial license) http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/solutions-on-module/digi-connect/digiconnectme.jsp#models

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this and unfortunately you'd need to port the latest version yourself using the .Net micro framework porting kit available from MS (which is open source).

Not a small job I imagine. So yes you can do it, but not easily.